# Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, utf-8, mamp

I have a problem about encoding charset, the fact is, when I test my website in local (MAMP PHP 5.5.3)
All works fine, my JSON object is returned without any problem.
But in prod with server hosted by dreamhost (PHP 5.4) it doesn't work and throw me this error

**json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument**.

(It's an error thrown by `Laravel` on file `JsonResponse.php` with the `setData` method).

So, How is it possible to have an error on my online servor and not on my local one?

**EDIT:**

This is my response header:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1371
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 02 Oct 2014 11:56:30 GMT
Expires:Thu, 02 Oct 2014 11:56:31 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=100
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

should be : `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8` ?

But I can not override the header..
This is not working :

```
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->header('charset', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Do you want us to just guess what the problem is? Show the code.

Comment: In fact The only thing I want to know is why there is an encoding charset problem on my online server but not on my local one..

Comment: Is the configuration identical? Something must be different.

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` what you are trying to encode with `::setData()`?

Comment: The fact is that my object content french string, so there is some accents. I can solve the problème with a recursive function applying an utf8_encode on each string value but it transform some caraters  for exemple the "é" becomes "A©".

Don't know why. And I can't access to my apache/php conf on my dreamhost server.

Comment: Where does the string you want to encode come from ?

Comment: My Database and my database is in utf8_unicode_ci like my tables and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had `setLocale('fr_FR')` now I have `setLocale('fr_FR.UTF8')` and it solves the problem!

Laravel doesn't throw any error anymore using json_encode() for any AJAX request. my strftime function return the right characters fo each letter with an accent.